# Excel function to find next higher value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have data like below. I am calculating third column (next higher date. For each unique values of created date for data, I need to know what is next higher date available for data. There are duplicates. Also if there is no next higher date then I use generic date of 1/1/2017.

Last date = 1/1/2017

[image: Sample data]

Now my question here is how can I achieve this using INDEX/MATCH or LARGE functions or do I need to use VBA scripting to get my results?

Comment: Does your version of excel have the MINIFS function?

Answer (score 1):

Per the sample image, put one if these in this in C2 and drag down.

```
'xl2003-xl2007
=MIN(MIN(INDEX(B$2:B$99+((A$2:A$99<>A2)+(B$2:B$99<=B2))*1E+99, , )), DATE(2017, 1, 1))
'xl2010-xl2013
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15, 7, B$2:B$99/((A$2:A$99=A2)*(B$2:B$99>B2)), 1), DATE(2017, 1, 1))
'xl2016/Office 365
=IFERROR(MINIFS(B:B, A:A, A2, B:B, ">"&B2), DATE(2017, 1, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks..I used this one since IFERROR was not working when result was 0 =IF(MINIFS(E:E, B:B, B2, E:E, ">"&E2) <> 0, MINIFS(E:E, B:B, B2, E:E, ">"&E2), DATE(2017,1,1))